# How to create an alert below a field in form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem:** I have the form and overall is working fine. However, I would like to create an alert that show below the field where its empty.

The form look like this:

[image]

Instead for the alert to appear like so:

[image]

I would like to have the alert like the following:

[image]

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Add the `required` attribute to the field

Comment: you have to use third party plugin for it. check this https://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/

Comment: Do you tried `required` arttr : `<input type="...." ...  required>` ?

Comment: I have tried required. It does not work and it is not supported in safari

Comment: @KD: There wouldnt be a way for one to create it and if so how would you start?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the default html5 alert like the one in the picture u need to:

- 1. Make sure u specify that it is html5 by doing

  at the top of the page
- 2. Add the required attribute to the input

to add it do this:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

this should work

Comment: put <!DOCTYPE html> where it is empty ^

Comment: @Roberto Flores did u specify that it is html 5 ?

Comment: I have tried this and it does not populate nor work on my end